# Puzzled by the max number records of a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, partitioning

I am working with a web site analyser which will be used to analyse our own site according to the log from tomcat.

Now,we push the log from tomcat to the database (MySQL) everyday, it works well now. However I found a potential and fatal problem !

Until now we push the log to a single table in the database,but the log items will increase rapidly soon especially when we hold more users, obviously a single table can not save so many log items (also it will result in a low performance when do the query operation from the **large** table).

And we use the hibernate as the persistence layer,each row in the log table is mapped to a java object of LogEntry in the application.

I have thought create a new table each month,but how to make the LogEntry map to more than one tables and query across tables?

Also,the log number of each month maybe not the same, an extreme example, how about the log number (records in the table) is greater than the max capacity of the table in db?

Then I thought set a property to limit the max number of log to be pushed when hibernate push log to db. If so I have no idea to tell the hibernate create a new table and query across table automatically.

Any ideas?

**Update to  Sandy:**

I know your meaning, that's to say the max capability of a table is decided by the OS, and if I use the partitioning, the max capability maybe increase until it up to the max capability of my disk. However even if I use the partition, it seems that I do not need to care about the max capability of the table, but if the table hold too many records, it will result in a low performance. (BTW, we have not decide to delete the old logs yet.) Another way I thought is create more than tables with the same structure,but I am using the hibernate,all of the log inserting and querying will through the hibernate, and can the Entity (POJO) mapped to more than one table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have thought create a new table each month, but how to make the LogEntry map to more than one tables and query across tables?

Have a look at [Hibernate Shards](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html) (database sharding is a method of horizontal partitioning). Although this suproject is not very active and has some limitations (refer to the documentation), it's stable and usable (Hibernate Shards has been [contributed by Max Ross](http://highscalability.com/sharding-hibernate-way) from Google who is using it internally).

> Also,the log number of each month maybe not the same,a extreme example, how about the log number(records in the table) is greater than the max capacity of the table in db?

Monitor your database/tables and anticipate the required maintenance.

> If so I have no idea to tell the hibernate create a new table and query accross table automatically.

Hibernate won't do that automatically, this will be part of the maintenance of the database and of the sharding configuration (see also the section about [Virtual Shards](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/shards/3.0/reference/en/html_single/#shards-resharding-virtual)).

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is very useful for me , I will have a look ,. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider horizontal partitioning.

> #### Horizontal Partitioning
>
> this form of
>   partitioning segments table rows so
>   that distinct groups of physical
>   row-based datasets are formed that can
>   be addressed individually (one
>   partition) or collectively (one-to-all
>   partitions). All columns defined to a
>   table are found in each set of
>   partitions so no actual table
>   attributes are missing. An example of
>   horizontal partitioning might be a
>   table that contains ten years worth of
>   historical invoice data being
>   partitioned into ten distinct
>   partitions, where each partition
>   contains a single year's worth of
>   data.data.
>
> #### Increased performance - during scan
>
> operations, the MySQL optimizer knows
>   what partitions contain the data that
>   will satisfy a particular query and
>   will access only those necessary
>   partitions during query execution. ***For
>   example, a million row table may be
>   broken up into ten different
>   partitions in range style so that each
>   partition contains 100,000 rows***. ***If a
>   query is issued that only needs data
>   from one of the partitions, and a
>   table scan operation is necessary,
>   only 100,000 rows will be accessed
>   instead of a million.** Obviously, it is
>   much quicker for MySQL to sample
>   100,000 rows than one million so the
>   query will complete much sooner. The
>   same benefit is derived should index
>   access be possible as local
>   partitioned indexes are created for
>   partitioned tables. Finally, it is
>   possible to stripe a partitioned table
>   across different physical drives by
>   specifying different file
>   system/directory paths for specific
>   partitions. This allows physical I/O
>   contention to be reduced when multiple
>   partitions are accessed at the same
>   time.

Checkout this article [Improving Database Performance with Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html)

### Update

> *It seems that the Horizontal Partitioning can handle the large table, but how about if the number of the record is greater than the max size of the table?*
>
> Actually, max size of mysql table is determined by Operating System constraints. Have a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html), and determine yourself. 
>   Alternative option is to purge old log records periodically, only if they are not required for analysis.
>   Create a cron job or any scheduled task to do the deleting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that the **Horizontal Partitioning** can handle the large table,but how about if the number of the record is greater than the max size of the table?

Comment: @Sandy--Thanks for the update,I update my answer also. Please have a look. :)